# How can I compare a value from C# Viewbag in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to compare a boolean value from the `Viewbag` in javascript. So at first I tried this:

```
if (@Viewbag.MyBoolValue)
    do_sth();
```

But then I have error in console like: `Value False/True is not declared` (not exactly).

So I tried this:

```
@{
    string myBool = ((bool)Viewbag.MyBoolValue) ? "true" : "false";
}
```

and in javascript:

```
if (@myBool == "true")
    do_sth();
```

But it does not work too. How can I make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: If you were truly attempting to use a C# string in JavaScript, you would use `'@myString'` or `"@myString"`. The value gets thrown in there literally with no typing (obviously).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you have should work, assuming that the value from the ViewBag is of a type which javascript can understand.

Note however, that your first example most likely did not work because boolean values are lowercase in javascript and uppercase in C#. With that in mind, try this:

```
var myBoolValue = @ViewBag.MyBoolValue.ToString().ToLower();
if (myBoolValue)
    do_sth();
```

Comment: Viewbag could be case sensitive: ViewBag

Answer (score 1):

The below will create a javascript vailable with value from viewbag

```
<script>
    var myBoolInJs = @Viewbag.MyBoolValue;
    if(myBoolInJs == true)
     do_sth();
</script>
```

Comment: @MateuszRogulski sorry my bad you don't need the HtmlRaw, I just typed it far too quickly

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBoolVal = @((ViewBag.MyBoolValue ?? false).ToString().ToLower());
```

or

```
var myBoolVal = '@(ViewBag.MyBoolValue)'==='@true';
```

or

```
 var myBoolVal = @(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyBoolValue ?? false));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
@{     
   string myBool = Viewbag.MyBoolValue.ToString().ToLower(); 
}

if (@myBool)
    do_sth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted true and false use 0 and 1 in your controller, on top of razor page

```
@{ 
    var isSomething= Viewbag.MyBoolValue;
}
```

Later down

```
if (@isSomething== 0)
```