# How to get bool value from ViewBag on view?

Tags: c#, jquery, viewbag

I am trying to receive bool values from ViewBag.

But the issue is that to receive value I am using:

```
var test = '@ViewBag.Test'
```

In this way value will be `'True'` or `'False'` (string). Of cource I can use something like `if (test == 'True')` but, is there a way to get from ViewBag bool value dirrectly, or at least convert it?

**EDIT:**

I need to get ViewBag value in javascript part.

Comment: show, how you set this variable

Comment: Use a viewmodel instead of a viewbag. it's a slight bit more overhead to set up since you need to define everything in a class, but will save your sanity in the long run. are you trying to use the variable in JS or in razor?

Comment: In js. In perspective yes, it will be changed to model, but right now, I need ViewBag.

Comment: Can't you just change `var test = '@ViewBag.Test';`  to  `var test = @ViewBag.Test;`   ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213732/how-can-i-compare-a-value-from-c-sharp-viewbag-in-javascript

Answer (score 9):

You could use unboxing:

```
var test = @((bool)(ViewBag.Test??false))
```

Condensed into single line, handles missing ViewBag element.
Null coalescing operator returns the value of ViewBag.Test or false if "Test" doesn't exist. Finally value is typecast.

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what it adds to the existing answers.

Answer (score 7):

In controller code is
`ViewBag.Test = true;`

**In View code is**

```
var test=@(ViewBag.Test.ToString().ToLower());
console.log(test);
```

Now the data type of variable test is a bool. So you can use:

```
if(test)
    alert('true');
else 
    alert('false')
```

Answer (score 4):

If your value is `bool` in controller then use cshtml page

```
bool test='@ViewBag.Test';
```

As `viewbag` needs not casting I think when you assign your value in a `bool` variable it gives you `bool` value in your view(cshtml) page

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove quotes `var test = @ViewBag.Test`

Answer (score 0):

Only need:

```
<script>
   var test = '@ViewBag.Test';
   if(test)
       {console.log(test);}
   else
       {console.log(test);};
</script>
```